# Can stranded wire in a crimp (bootlace) ferrule be used in lieu of a pigtail to terminate to devices that require solid wire?

Tags: electrical, wiring

As we all know, some device termination types do not accept stranded wire (14-10AWG), which is quite a shame on a conduit job or when using stranded THHN for pigtailing.  However, in some applications, such as when terminating under a terminal block, a bootlace ferrule (such as the ones shown below) can be crimped on the end of a stranded wire to effectively "make it solid" for termination purposes.

[image: insulated crimp (bootlace) ferrules]

Can such a crimp/bootlace ferrule be used to "adapt" stranded wire to device terminations (such as pressure plates, as not all are rated for stranded wire) that take solid wire only? (Obviously, I doubt you'd want to try to bend them around a side-screw terminal.)

Comment: Would tinning the end of a stranded wire before inserting into the ferrule and crimping improve the electrical and mechanical connection?

Comment: @JimStewart -- actually, no -- tinning the end of a stranded wire can make it rather stiff and brittle, and prone to breakage at the point where it exits the ferrule/crimp connector

Comment: So you can't use a solid-wire pigtail in a device box fed by stranded wire of the same gauge?

Comment: @Edwin -- you *can* but it may be held against your box fill (it certainly takes up box space, which can be in quite short supply in some situations)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel What about tinning of stranded wires for splices to solid wire with twist-on connectors? What about tinning of the stranded leads of an Eaton whole house surge protector into a breaker and under screws in the ground and neutral bars?

Comment: @JimStewart -- stuff in the panel generally supports stranded wire

Comment: I use ferules for use under clamps all the time there are versions that accommodate more than 1 wire. Equipment being built and shipped to some other countries ferules are required. I do not use stabs and believe the hard plating on the ferule would further reduce the ability for the stab to grab the wire (plus ferrules are usually shorter than the required strip length).

Comment: Thank youfor asking that TPE!  @EdBeal Yes, because those wires are often going into Euro style terminal blocks, which are screw tightened similar to the inlets on most breakers.   They give me a Euro block with every cheap LED light I buy, and I tear the ferrules off and wirenut.  The ferrule would further enlarge the diameter of an already slightly larger stranded wire, making it off-spec for the stabs, unless *shudder* multi-size stabs...

Comment: The way I look at the NEC is they want devices to be rated or listed for the job unless the local jurisdiction says otherwise. I would look at it like this: if the device says it's rated for stranded, then use only stranded no matter the termination. Same for solid wiring devices. To dive deeper, even if the terminal is rated for either, a ferrule might still be a violation as the terminal expects actual wire as that is how it was designed and tested. So you would have to contact the manufacturer and inquire if the device is suitable for use with ferrule crimped stranded.